# Spring 5 MVC with spring-cloud-sleuth-otel

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, open-telemetry

Can we have sleuth with Otel for non spring boot applications?
Please share inputs.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Spring Cloud Sleuth OTel requires Boot based applications.